# Intriguing properties of power tower function

Tags: functional-analysis, complex-analysis, power-towers

I was talking with an acquaintance and he proposed an interesting function:

> Consider a number $x$. Take the fraction $\frac{x}{x - 1}$, and raise it to the power $\frac{3x}{3x - 1}$. Iterate this process until the value converges.

Mathematically, this function looks like:

$$
f(x) = \left(\frac{3^0 x}{(3^0x)-1}\right)
            ^{\left(\frac{3^1x}{(3^1x)-1}\right)
            ^{\left(\frac{3^2x}{(3^2x)-1}\right)
            ^{\left(\frac{3^3x}{(3^3x)-1}\right)
            ^{...}}}}
$$

This is a power tower where the exponents converge to 1, so $f(x)$ converges if it exists (DNE for $x = 1$). For example:

$$
f(2) = \frac{2}{1}
            ^{\frac{6}{5}
            ^{\frac{18}{17}
            ^{\frac{54}{53}
            ^{...}}}} \approx 2.47363...
$$

The function for $x \in (-100, 100)$ [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuRrJ.png); I think it's rather interesting [how it differs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prQT3.png) from its "parent" function, $g(x) = \frac{x}{x - 1}$, (in particular in the <s>range</s> domain $x \in (-1, 0)$, [shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqPtc.png)).

Interestingly, while $f(x)$ is not defined at $x = 1$, the function is complex-valued in the <s>range</s> domain $x \in (0, 1)$, although unfortunately I lack the wherewithal to provide a nice-looking contour plot of the complex outputs.

I'd like to ask whether some of the more advanced mathematicians on this site can comment on either of both of:

1. The integral $\int_{1^+}^{\infty} \left[f(x) - g(x)\right] dx$. It seems tantalizingly similar to the Euler-Mascheroni constant in theme.
2. The behavior of $f(x)$ in the <s>range</s> domain $x \in (0, 1)$. I'm not especially well-versed in complex analysis, so I would love any commentary.

Thanks!

Comment: Range is usually for $y=f(x)$ instead of $x$. Also, do you want the behavior on $-1<x<0$ or $0<x<1$? A complex plot is [here](https://samuelj.li/complex-function-plotter/#(z%2F(z-1))%5E(t*z%2F(t*z-1))%5E%20(t%5E2*z%2F(t%5E2*z-1))%5E(t%5E3*z%2F(t%5E3*z-1))%5E%20(t%5E4*z%2F(t%5E4*z-1))%5E(t%5E5*z%2F(t%5E5*z-1))%5E%20(t%5E6**z%2F(t%5E6*z-1))%5E(t%5E7*z%2F(t%5E7*z-1))) with adjustable $t$.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I was lazy with my language; I was using "range" in the colloquial programming sense, when I meant domain. Thank you for the complex plot!